# Firebase + GTM not working on android release APK

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

GA is not reporting numbers when the APK is in release, but works on debug APK.

the app is built with react-native android.

firebase is working fine in both APK builds but GA is only working with debug

google tag manager version = google play services = 17.0.0

here is verbose log for release APK

```html
1585815498.662 15888-15931/my.app.package V/GoogleTagManager: Initializing Tag Manager.
1585815498.663 15888-15931/my.app.package V/GoogleTagManager: Looking up container asset.
1585815498.665 15888-15931/my.app.package V/GoogleTagManager: Asset found for container GTM-XXXXXX
1585815498.665 15888-15931/my.app.package W/GoogleTagManager: Ignoring container asset google-services.json (does not match (gtm-[a-z0-9]{1,10})\.json)
1585815498.665 15888-15931/my.app.package I/GoogleTagManager: Loading container GTM-XXXXXX
1585815498.667 15888-15931/my.app.package I/GoogleTagManager: Installing Tag Manager event handler.
1585815498.667 15888-16033/my.app.package V/GoogleTagManager: Starting to load container GTM-XXXXXX.
1585815498.667 15888-15931/my.app.package I/GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager event handler installed.
1585815498.667 15888-15931/my.app.package I/GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager initilization took 5ms
1585815498.681 15888-16033/my.app.package V/GoogleTagManager: Container GTM-XXXXXXis scheduled for loading.
1585815498.684 15888-16033/my.app.package V/GoogleTagManager: Starting to fetch a new resource
1585815498.685 15888-16033/my.app.package V/GoogleTagManager: Attempting to fetch container GTM-XXXXXX from network
1585815498.687 15888-16033/my.app.package V/GoogleTagManager: Container GTM-XXXXXX loaded.
1585815498.690 15888-16038/my.app.package V/GoogleTagManager: Starting to load resource from Network.
1585815498.691 15888-16038/my.app.package V/GoogleTagManager: Loading resource from https://www.google-analytics.com/gtm/android?id=GTM-XXXXXX&pv=-1&rv=5.0
1585815498.742 15888-16033/my.app.package V/GoogleTagManager: Added event _s to pending queue.
1585815498.814 15888-16033/my.app.package V/GoogleTagManager: Added event _vs to pending queue.
1585815499.290 15888-16038/my.app.package V/GoogleTagManager: The container was successfully parsed from the resource
1585815499.308 15888-16038/my.app.package V/GoogleTagManager: The runtime configuration was successfully parsed from the resource
1585815499.309 15888-16038/my.app.package V/GoogleTagManager: Container resource successfully loaded from Network
1585815499.327 15888-16076/my.app.package V/GoogleTagManager: Resource GTM-XXXXXX saved on Disk.
1585815499.349 15888-16033/my.app.package V/GoogleTagManager: Container GTM-XXXXXX loaded during runtime initialization.
1585815499.350 15888-16033/my.app.package V/GoogleTagManager: Evaluating tags for pending event gtm.load
1585815499.352 15888-16033/my.app.package V/GoogleTagManager: Evaluating trigger Positive predicates: [Properties: {arg1=screenView, function=_eq, arg0=Event Name} pushAfterEvaluate: null] Negative predicates: [] Add tags: [Properties: {vtp_overrideGaSettings=true, vtp_contentGroup=[{index=1, group=cnt_showName}, {index=4, group=platform}, {index=3, group=usr_type}, {index=2, group=cnt_tags}], vtp_trackingId=gaID, vtp_enableFirebaseEcommerce=true, vtp_trackType=TRACK_SCREENVIEW, vtp_metric=[{metric=1, index=1}], vtp_enableUaRlsa=false, once_per_event=true, vtp_enableRecaptchaOption=false, vtp_enableFirebaseCampaignData=true, vtp_collectAdid=true, function=__ua, vtp_dimension=[{index=1, dimension=sony android native tv}, {index=2, dimension=production}, {index=4, dimension=cnt_showName}, {index=5, dimension=cnt_showType}, {index=6, dimension=cnt_showEpisodeNo}, {index=7, dimension=cnt_showSeason}, {index=8, dimension=cnt_mediaType}, {index=9, dimension=usr_id}, {index=10, dimension=usr_type}, {index=14, dimension=cnt_plusContent}, {index=21, dimension=pageAddress}, {index=22, dimension=cnt_showLanguages}, {index=23, dimension=cnt_tags}, {index=24, dimension=usr_subscriptionPlanID}, {index=41, dimension=Advertiser ID}, {index=42, dimension=usr_id}, {index=43, dimension=usr_type}, {index=45, dimension=cnt_bcmMediaID}, {index=46, dimension=cnt_bcmShowSeasonID}, {index=47, dimension=cnt_showID}, {index=48, dimension=usr_subscriptionPlanID}, {index=3, dimension=cnt_language}, {index=76, dimension=usr_kidAge}, {index=75, dimension=usr_profileID}, {index=77, dimension=cnt_maxAge}, {index=78, dimension=SourceOfInteraction}], tag_id=28, vtp_fieldsToSet=[{fieldName=&uid, value=usr_id}, {fieldName=appId, value=App ID}, {fieldName=appName, value=App Name}, {fieldName=appVersion, value=App Version Code}, {fieldName=ate, value=Advertiser Tracking Enabled}, {fieldName=idfa, value=Advertiser ID}, {fieldName=screenName, value=pageAddress}], vtp_enableUseInternalVersion=false} pushAfterEvaluate: null] Remove tags: []
1585815499.352 15888-16033/my.app.package V/GoogleTagManager: Beginning to evaluate variable Event Name
1585815499.352 15888-16033/my.app.package V/GoogleTagManager: Executing: __e
1585815499.353 15888-16033/my.app.package V/GoogleTagManager: Done evaluating variable Event Name
1585815499.353 15888-16033/my.app.package V/GoogleTagManager: Executing: 2
1585815611.835 15888-16033/my.app.package V/GoogleTagManager: Non-passthrough event _vs doesn’t get logged to Firebase directly. (edited)
```

Comment: Hi Abdullah, just to let you know this kind of question would probably be better served as an issue on their github repo.

Comment: Thank you , can you share with me the link for their github repo?

Comment: If you post in one of these, they'll probably point you in the right direction https://github.com/googleanalytics/